# redirect to another view(Codeigniter) with jquery tabs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, tabs

I'm a beginner in routing web url, i have tried to just redirect normal `html` but it gives me some weird problems (`pagination` not working, `session` not working, etc).

[This](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=115381745327294&set=vb.219494334779597&type=2&theater) question showed us how to redirect `jquery` `tabs` to another `html` page. Now, i want to redirect to another `view` each time the user clicked the tabs (`Codeigniter` framework).

How to do this?

Normally, we use this code in the `controller` :

```
$this->load->view('your_view');
```

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: jQuery can't run PHP code.. It can just redirect you to a new page or it can make ajax request to load different data produced by your PHP code..
PHP is server side language (it works at the moment when your server is responding to your request) while Javascript(jQuery) is user side (it can take actions inside user browser on some event..)..

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it.

1) If you tabs support ajax loading of contents, then by clicking on a tab, you can call a specific controller action / member function. In that function you can load your desired view. This way all the CI features like pagination, sessions will work fine.

2) You can also get the whole data for all the tabs in the controller (where the view for the tabs is loaded), and then load all the views for each tab in the tabs view using

```
$this->load->view('your-view');
```

As you have already fetched all the data needed for each tab view, so you will be able to process that data in each tabs views.

Hopefully this will help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You would use Ajax to request a page, then return the VIEW AS A STRING by setting the third parameter TRUE

```
public function requestPageViaAjax()
{
    if(!$this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {
        return show_error('Method not allowed!');
    }

    $this->load->view('views/page', array(), TRUE);//partially loaded view
}
```

**Note:** if your calling a page via Ajax, make sure you call the pagination via Ajax also!! Otherwise you will run into routing problems